# Функция срабатывает 2 раза (при запуске кода и по таймеру)

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, schedule

Что необходимо добиться: получить из 1 запроса export_id, положить его в переменную и отправить во втором запросе для получения данных. Выполнять это необходимо 1 раз в сутки в определенное время. Мой код:
(P.S. логин и ключи доступа к api неверные)

```
import requests
import time
import schedule
import datetime as DT
import json


account_name = "100"
today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#Данные для запроса Export_ID
BASE_URL_EXPORT_ID = f"https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/users"
params_export_id = {'key' : '9NDOA',
          'created_at[from]' : today_str,
          'created_at[to]': today_str}

def run():
    print('Получаем Export_id')
    today_str = DT.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    #получаем export_id 
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL_EXPORT_ID, params=params_export_id)
    data = response.json()
    print (data)
    #пытаюсь сохранить данные для 2 части запроса :)
    export_id = data['info']['export_id']
    return export_id

export_id = run()
schedule.every().day.at("12:09").do(run)

#Данные для получение информации
params_data = {'key' : '9NDOA'}
BASE_URL_DATA = f"https://{account_name}.getcourse.ru/pl/api/account/exports/{export_id}"
   
    
def run1():
    #получаю сами данные
    response1 = requests.get(BASE_URL_DATA, params=params_data)
    result1 = response1.json()
    #print(response1.request.url)
    #Отбираю нужные ключи из запроса
    print(result1)
    a = result1['info']['fields']
    b = result1['info']['items']
    #Делаю красиво :)
    a_and_b = [dict(zip(a, x)) for x in b]
    q = (json.dumps(a_and_b, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
    print(q)
    
schedule.every().day.at("12:09").do(run1)
    
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    #time.sleep(1)

while True:
    schedule.run1_pending()
    #time.sleep(1)
```

по запросу export_id получаю:  `{'success': True, 'info': {'export_id': 378771}, 'error_message': '', 'error': False}`

отсюда мне необходимо забрать значение export_id, в данном случае 378771 и положить его в переменную export_id которая в последствии уйдет во 2 запрос на получение данных.

В чем заключается проблема:

1. функция run срабатывает 2 раза (1 раз при запуске скрипта, второй раз по таймеру который установлен).
2. данные которые я получаю при запуске скрипта записываются в переменную, а те которые получаю по таймеру нет! (по старому номеру экспорта нельзя получить данные).
3. в while Truе я закоментил строку с таймеров, иначе все вообще перестает работать дальше 1 функции (run)

Это мой наверное 5 вопрос, буду очень благодарен если поможете мне все-таки закрыть данный вопрос :)

Comment: Почему бы не объединить функции?

Comment: А что за второй странный цикл с `schedule.run1_pending()`??

Comment: @Za Ars, а это решит проблему №1?

Comment: Сделайте функцию, которая будет вызывать первую функцию, получать из неё нужный вам `id` и вызывать с этим `id` вторую функцию. И вот эту объединяющую функцию вызывайте в шедулере. Иначе придётся делать через глобальные переменные, что не хорошо. Или куда-то сохранять данные в базу или на диск.

Comment: решит, так как внутри 1 циклы вы получите id для второй, просто придется вызывать их последовательно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вашем месте я бы использовал [APscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html). В примере код, который запускает `job_function` каждые 24 часа. Ваш код станет проще и чище настолько, что сами сможете дописать оставшийся функционал.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def job_function():
    print "Hello World"

sched = BlockingScheduler()

# Schedules job_function to be run every day
sched.add_job(job_function, 'interval', hours=24)

sched.start()
```

Comment: Но это никак не отвечает на вопрос. Поправьте ответ так, чтобы он отвечал на вопрос. заданный автором.

Comment: @ZaArs, использование этой библиотеки избавит от проблемы №1, так как функция будет вызываться 1 раз каждый день. Если засунуть необходимые действия в одну функцию `job_function`, то это избавит от проблемы №2. Также отпадет проблема №3, так как цикл while вообще будет не нужен.

Comment: Да и как можно ответить на вопрос, которого нет?) Автор лишь указал на проблемы в коде

Comment: @Xon lon, а в  APscheduler есть возможность вызывать функцию в определенное время? или мне надо будет запустить скрипт ровно в то время которое мне необходимо, чтобы он работал? :)

Comment: @Vadim, конечно, [есть](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/cron.html), для этого используйте `sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', month='1-12', day='1-31', hour=6, minute=30)`

Comment: Ну помочь решить проблемы. Тут большинство вопросов с проблемами

Comment: @Xon lon, Ваш совет полезен. Но к сожалению не закрывает потребность полностью. Сделать 1 большую функцию не получается из-за оператора "return" с помощью которого я передаю значение в переменную. Он функцию обрубает и я до 2 запроса уже просто не дохожу.

Comment: @Vadim, а разве примерно [такой](https://pastebin.com/LxM8bUCu) вариант не сработает? Извините за псевдокод, сейчас нет возможности протестировать, но суть, я думаю, вы уловили